# Promotions code combination from one pool not possible

Tags: shopware, shopware6, promotions

ist it possible to use two promotion codes from one promotion-code-pool in one order?
The promotion is set to

**Max. total uses : unlimited**

**Max. uses per customer : unlimited**

I can combine one code of this promotion in one order with other promotions, but i am unable to combine two codes from the same promotion-pool.

example:

we give out promotion codes for 25 €. if a customer happens two have two or more of them and wants to use them in one order, right now its not possible and i dont see where its limited.
when the customer has a 50 € promotion code and a 25 € promotion code he can combine them.

How do i have to configure promotions to allow users to use more than one code of the same promotion pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at this point in time it is not possible. One and the same promotion can only be redeemed once per cart.

Comment: do u know of any existing issues regarding that, or should i create one if this is important to us?

Comment: i created a ticket

https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-22485

Answer (score 0):

You should set "max uses" empty. The system will check which specific coupon id is used and will then make that one invalid. You can also see the name of the client who used it.